# не верный вывод метода Anagram

Tags: java

должно получиться
E.g. "abcd efgh" => "dcba hgfe"

E.g. "**a**1bcd efg!h" => "d1cb**a** hgf!e"

```
class Anagram {
static String makeAnagram(String sentence) {
    char[] array = sentence.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    int j = array.length - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(array[i])) {
            i++;
        } else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(array[j])) {
            j--;
        } else {
            char tempChar = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tempChar;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return new String(array);
}

private String reverseWord(String word) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдет это решение:

```
String string = "abcd efgh";
for (String splitString : string.split(" ", 2)) {
    Log.i("log__", "   - " + splitString);
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(splitString).reverse().toString();
    Log.i("log__", "   - " + reverse);
}

//должно получиться E.g. "abcd efgh" => "dcba hgfe"
I/log__:    - abcd
I/log__:    - dcba
I/log__:    - efgh
I/log__:    - hgfe
```

**update**

> суть в том что бы полностью строчка была как в ответе.. и все что не
>   есть литералами оставалось на своих метстах тоесть: "a1bcd efg!h" =>
>   "d1cba hgf!e" тоесть слова и спец символы остаються на своих местах

```
public String makeAnagram(String in) {
        String alf = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        Log.i("log__", "  входное выражение - " + in);
        Log.i("log__", "------------------------------------------- - ");
        //разделяем входную на слова по пробелу
        for (String splitIn : in.split(" ", 2)) {
            Log.i("log__", "  входное слово - " + splitIn);

            //преобразуем входное слово в массив char
            char[] array = splitIn.toCharArray();

            StringBuilder sbSim = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (alf.contains(String.valueOf(array[i]))) {
                    sbSim.append(array[i]);//собираем слово только из букв афавита
                }
            }
            Log.i("log__", "  слово из букв алфавита - " + sbSim.toString());

            String reverseSbSim = new StringBuilder(sbSim.toString()).reverse().toString();
            Log.i("log__", "  перевернутое слово из букв алфавита - " + reverseSbSim);

            //преобразуем перевернутое слово из букв алфавита в массив char
            char[] reversSbSimChar = reverseSbSim.toCharArray();
            int k = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (alf.contains(String.valueOf(array[i]))) {
                    array[i] = reversSbSimChar[k];
                    k++;
                } else {
                    array[i] = array[i];
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                out.append(array[i]);
            }

            Log.i("log__", "------------------------------------------- - ");
            Log.i("log__", "------------------------------------------- - ");
            out.append(" ");
        }
        Log.i("log__", "  результат - " + out.toString().trim());
        return out.toString().trim();
    }
```

**логи**

```
I/log__:   входное выражение - d25obroe utr56o
I/log__: ------------------------------------------- - 
I/log__:   входное слово - d25obroe
I/log__:   слово из букв алфавита - dobroe
I/log__:   перевернутое слово из букв алфавита - eorbod
I/log__: ------------------------------------------- - 
I/log__: ------------------------------------------- - 
I/log__:   входное слово - utr56o
I/log__:   слово из букв алфавита - utro
I/log__:   перевернутое слово из букв алфавита - ortu
I/log__: ------------------------------------------- - 
I/log__: ------------------------------------------- - 
I/log__:   результат - e25orbod ort56u
```

Comment: суть в том что бы полностью строчка была как в ответе.. и все что не есть литералами оставалось на своих метстах
тоесть: "a1bcd efg!h" => "d1cba hgf!e" тоесть слова и спец символы остаються на своих местах